# Setting nginx upstream server to down on timeout

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have an nginx(OSS) load balancer in front of two application servers. However after each application server is restarted it has high CPU load thus resulting in client timeouts for several minutes.

Is there any way to mark the restarted server down either manually through command line (i.e. not by editing the nginx.conf and restarting) or by using some timeout directive of the nginx to  set the restarted server temporarily down?

Comment: Afaik, nginx cannot do this. You should have a look at another solution, like [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/)

Comment: Indeed HAProxy has a wealth of solutions on this

Comment: So go ahead with it ^^